# can't boot to ubuntu because of 100% disk & infinite service restart

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, boot

i have a ubuntu server that has system service, the system service are won't run (and always restarted) because of the disk usage are 100% (no space left on disk), is there any way to login into ubuntu in this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

You can boot to Ubuntu via recovery mode (as root mode); then you need to disable some service that stuck on boot.

1. how do you boot into recovery mode in Ubuntu server?

restart your server until a grup display shown, there will be 2 option, ubuntu and recover mode, choose recovery mode then choose recovery mode again, then there will be option to login into cmd as root

2. In any case the obvious solution is to free disk space, not disable services. Disabling services will have no effect.

yeah, even when i delete 2GB of data, my service still want more disk space, so the alternative solution is disabling the service

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question, but it would be good to provide a little detail on what to do. This is a fairly bare and useless answer. For example, how do you boot into recovery mode in Ubuntu server? In any case the obvious solution is to free disk space, not disable services. Disabling services will have no effect.

Comment: @Kurankat answer edited